# Does a comma always separate the nonfinite clause from the main clause?

Tags: grammar

Does a comma always separate a nonfinite clause (particularly one that contains a present participle) from the main clause of a sentence.

"I have called to heaven hoping for an answer." 
vs.
"I have called to heaven, hoping for an answer."

Which is the better choice? Thank you.

Comment: One example at the duplicate thread is << I came to work today(,) wearing my new suit. 
 >> I'd say that either punctuation is available here, and I'd say << I came to work today wearing my new suit. >> is nicely paraphrased << How I was dressed when I came to work today: I was  wearing my new suit. >> whereas << I came to work today, wearing my new suit. >> is best paraphrased <<  I came to work today. [And] I was wearing my new suit. >> _But (1) this is partly opinion-based, and (2) not all examples are so flexible._

Comment: You need the comma so that you—not heaven—are hoping for an answer.